# segmentation 11 in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a homework program in C. The program should take records from an input file and write those record to an output file. It seems like there is something wrong with the print_to_file function. I keep getting segmentation fault 11. Please help. My code is as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct car {        // create a struct type Car 
        char *license_plate;    
        int parking_spot;
        int num_tickets;
        int time_left;
    } Car;

    #define LICENSEPLATELENGTH 10

    Car* import_cars(char *filename, int numCars);
    void print_to_file(char* filename, Car* garage, int numCars);

    int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
        if(argc != 4)
            printf("Incorrect input.\n");
        else {
            int number = atoi(argv[1]);
            Car* parked_car = (Car*)malloc(sizeof(Car) * number);
            parked_car = import_cars(argv[2], number);
            print_to_file(argv[3], parked_car, number);
            free(parked_car);
        }
        return 0;
    }



     Car* import_cars(char* filename, int numCars)
{
    Car* inCar = (Car*)malloc(sizeof(Car) * numCars);
    inCar->license_plate = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 8); 
    //Question: How do I do if I the plate length is varied. How to malloc space to it?

    FILE* inFilePtr;
        if((inFilePtr = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
            printf("Error! Unable to open file %s. Check again.\n", *filename);
        else
        {
            int i = 0;
            fscanf(inFilePtr, "%s", inCar[i].license_plate);
            fscanf(inFilePtr, "%d%d%d", inCar[i].parking_spot, inCar[i].num_tickets, inCar[i].time_left);
            printf("%s %d %d %d \n", inCar[i].license_plate, inCar[i].parking_spot, inCar[i].num_tickets, inCar[i].time_left);
            for(i = 1; i < numCars; i++)
            {
                fscanf(inFilePtr, "%s", inCar[i].license_plate);
                fscanf(inFilePtr, "%d%d%d", inCar[i].parking_spot, inCar[i].num_tickets, inCar[i].time_left);
                printf("%s %d %d %d \n", inCar[i].license_plate, inCar[i].parking_spot, inCar[i].num_tickets, inCar[i].time_left);

            }
        }
    fclose(inFilePtr);
    return(inCar);
    //free(inCar.license_plate);  ` 
    //Question: Do I need to free space here would it remove the value 
    //stored in the variable which passed to main?
}
    void print_to_file(char* filename, Car* garage, int numCars) {
        FILE* outFilePtr;
        if((outFilePtr = fopen(filename, "w+")) == NULL){
            printf("Error! Cannot Open File %s!", *filename);
            printf("here\n");
        } else {
            int i = 0;
            for(i = 0; i < numCars; i++) {
                printf("%s\n%d %d %d\n", garage[i].license_plate, garage[i].parking_spot, garage[i].num_tickets, garage[i].time_left);
                fprintf(outFilePtr, "%s\n%d %d %d\n", garage[i].license_plate, garage[i].parking_spot, garage[i].num_tickets, garage[i].time_left);
            }   
        }
        fclose(outFilePtr);
    }
```

This is my input command.

```
./a.out 6 garage.txt output.txt
```

Here is what print in my terminal.

```
fi590dz 20 2 25 
57fjgmc 8 0 55 
7dkgjgu 25 1 15 
f9e829d 1 2 60 
4jgfd81 12 2 10 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

By the way, I'm pretty new in programming and really bad with debugging. Could you give me some tips of how to debug or any debugging tools? I use a mac so gdb doesn't work.

Comment: What does the input file look like? Can we have a sample?

Comment: `parked_car` : create by `malloc` => replace with return value of `import_cars`. It's local variable address => `free`ed it(not return of malloc).

Comment: On mac, you may be able to use lldb.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(Car) * number)` move into `import_cars`. use it reading and return. in main : `Car* parked_car = import_cars(argv[2], number);`

Comment: `printf("Error! Cannot Open File %s!", *filename);`Not dereference --> `printf("Error! Cannot Open File %s!", filename);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who met the issue here, I found the problem in my program. The problem is that I didn't allocate space for each of the `license_plate` pointer in the structure. So my way to solve it is add a line as below in the for loop of the `import_cars` function.

```
inCar[i].license_plate = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * LICENSEPLATELENGTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, because it’s a homework problem and you want to figure it out yourself, but here are some hints.

First, you really want to learn how to run your program in a debugger and get it to tell you which line crashed the program, and on which data.

Second, make sure you initialize the pointers for every element of the array before you try to read or write them.

Third, you’ll save yourself a lot of trouble if you initialize all your dynamic and local variables to zeroes, not garbage.  It will make a lot of bugs reproducible, make a lot of bugs crash immediately instead of corrupting memory, and also make it obvious when you debug that you’re using uninitialized data.

Therefore, I suggest you get in the habit of allocating your dynamic arrays with `calloc()`, not `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within your `parked_car = import_cars(argv[2], number);` and  `Car* import_cars(char* filename, int numCars);`functions.

Indeed in `Car* import_cars(char* filename, int numCars);` you are doing this:

```
Car inCar;
inCar.license_plate = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
```

So you are creating a local variable that is not accessible outside of the function (many different things can happen to the memory after the end of the function).

So when you do: `parked_car = import_cars(argv[2], number);` you are assigning to `parked_car` a `free`d variable.

A solution is to simply use the `parked_car`as an argument of your `import_cars()` function. All modifications made within the function will still be valid after it returns. So you should have:

```
void import_cars(char* filename, int numCars, Car* car);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is for the assignment, the prototype of each function is assigned, I can't change the prototype. Is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: By the way, I also updated my revised function. I use a pointer to pass the value of the structure to the main function, but I still got the segmentation fault.